Swig javascript v8 module did not self-register
On Ubuntu 22.04 running SWIG for javascript using v8. It compiles fine but when I try to run it "Module did not self-register".
==== run Nodejs example
SWIG Version 4.3.0
node v20.14.0
v8   11.3.244.8-node.23
==== swig
swig -c++ -javascript -v8 -Isrc -o debug/node_example_wrap.cxx src/example.i
==== gcc 1
c++ -std=c++20 -c src/example.c -o debug/node_example.o
==== gcc 2
c++ -c -fPIC -I /usr/include/node -I /usr/local/share/swig/4.3.0 debug/node_example_wrap.cxx -o debug/node_example_wrap.o
==== c++ shared
c++ -shared -std=c++20 debug/node_example.o debug/node_example_wrap.o -o debug/node_example.so
==== copy it
total 76
drwxrwxr-x 2 me me  4096 Oct 30 12:34 .
drwxrwxr-x 8 me me  4096 Oct 30 12:34 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 me me 65592 Oct 30 12:34 example.node
==== run it
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1454
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: Module did not self-register: '/home/me/projects/web/cpp/swig-c/out/js/example.node'.
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1454:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/me/projects/web/cpp/swig-c/test.js:1:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}

Node.js v20.14.0



I tried using node-gyp configure build and it fails to compile. looks like NODE_MODULE isn't defined for some reason.

$ node-gyp configure build
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@10.2.0
gyp info using node@20.14.0 | linux | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.12 found at "/usr/bin/python3"

gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args '/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args '-f',
gyp info spawn args 'make',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args '/home/me/projects/web/cpp/swig-c/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args '/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args '/home/me/.cache/node-gyp/20.14.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/me/.cache/node-gyp/20.14.0',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/lib/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/me/.cache/node-gyp/20.14.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/me/projects/web/cpp/swig-c',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args 'build',
gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory '/home/me/projects/web/cpp/swig-c/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/debug/node_example.so/debug/node_example_wrap.o
../debug/node_example_wrap.cxx:1933:12: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 1933 | NODE_MODULE(example, example_initialize)
      |            ^
make: *** [debug/node_example.so.target.mk:107: Release/obj.target/debug/node_example.so/debug/node_example_wrap.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/me/projects/web/cpp/swig-c/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:216:23)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-124-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/bin/node" "/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/bin/node-gyp" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/me/projects/web/cpp/swig-c
gyp ERR! node -v v20.14.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.2.0
gyp ERR! not ok 


tried various other responses to similar questions over the last couple days; no solution on any of them
tried "-javascript -node" same result
tried "-javascript -jsc" went down a rabbit hole of finding .h's and .so's could not resolve
used an older version of SWIG 4.0.2; did not work. Updated manually to 4.2.1. Also tried 4.3.0 (latest swig) failed the same way.
the same .i works for python and ruby on this OS and on macOS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
